# Arithmetic operation on Z3 bool variable

Tags: z3, boolean-logic, sat

I have a bunch of boolean variables in Z3, say `ai`, `bj`, and `ck`, to formulate my SAT problem. However, in my problem, there are three arithmetic constraints to be considered:

```
a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an = 1
b1 + b2 + b3 + ... + bn = 0
c1 + c2 + c3 + ... + cn <= 1
```

How can I formulate these three arithmetic constraints using Z3 API without changing the variable type (i.e., all boolean by default)?

Comment: Every tag has its own meaning and definition use it carefully

Answer (score 2):

You can embed Booleans into an if-expression, e.g., you can write

```
  if(a1,1,0) + if(a2,1,2) + ...
```

As a somewhat special purpose feature, it is also possible to enter 
cardinality constraints directly using built-in cardinality operators 
at this point from the C, .NET, and Java APIs, but not python nor Ocaml.
Also, the lia2pb tactic converts goals that use if-then-else expressions 
(as above) and converts them into Pseudo-Boolean constraints.

Comment: Hi Nikolai, thanks for your reply. Could you please be more specific? I am not quite understanding this.

Comment: An if-expression evaluates the first parameter as condition. If the condition is true, the expression returns the second parameter. The third parameter is returned, if the condition is false. In SMT syntax, this is known as ITE or if-then-else operator. If-expressions allow an elegant conversion from boolean to integer. A cardinality constraint defines how many variables have to evaluate to true. It can be of type at-least-k, at-most-k, exactly-k or between-n-and-m.